# Writing code in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently writing a JSON result onto a page using a for loop similar to the below example (simplified version):

```
var output = "";
for (i in response) {
    var ID = response[i].ID
    var name = response[i].name

    output += "<div id=\""+ID+"\">"+name+"</div>"
}

$("#allResults").html(output);
```

The output variable has become bloated & confusing.  Is there any way to write to the output variable without needing "" as it is particularly hard to insert variables & later modify the code?

Comment: You should use a templating or databinding engine, such as Handlebars or Knockout.

Comment: @Mr T, Try my handlebarjs templating answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below `HandlebarJS` Templating Snippet.
Include this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
```

Handlebar Template:

```
<script id="name-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each people}}
    <div id="{{ID}}">{{name}}.</div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content-placeholder"></div>
```

jQuery and Template Compilation:

```
$(function () {
  // Grab the template script
  var theTemplateScript = $("#name-template").html();

  // Compile the template
  var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);

  // This is the default context, which is passed to the template
  var context = {
    people: [ 
      { ID: 1000, name: 'Simpson' },
      { ID: 1001, name: 'Griffin' },
      { ID: 1002, name: 'Cartman' },
      { ID: 1003, name: 'McCormick' }
    ]
  };

  // Pass our data to the template
  var theCompiledHtml = theTemplate(context);

  // Add the compiled html to the page
  $('.content-placeholder').append(theCompiledHtml);
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for (sort of).  The JSON array that is returned from a third party API has a varying response quantity, but I should be able to work with this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following in an attempt to make it look 'simpler'

```
var allResults = $("#allResults");
for ( i in response ) {
    var ID = response[i].ID,
        name = response[i].name;

    $('<div/>')
        .attr('id', ID)
        .html(name)
        .appendTo(allResults);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am looking to put a lot more content into the output in the production model, so I'd probably end up with as big a maintenance task with this, but thanks for your answer as its straight forward for simple inputs as per my example.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need to be doing is creating DOM elements to represent the DOM, not strings which represent the DOM.

*Document Object Model: A record of the elements on the page and their associated values.*

To create an element, jQuery offers several shortcuts

```
span = $("<span>");
div = $("<div >");
anchor = $("<anchor >");
//etc.
```

To connect these elements to each other use `append`.

So using these, you can recreate some of these simple structures

```
//<div id="hi"></div>
var hi = $('<div>');
hi[0].id = "hi";

//<div id="foo"><span>Bar</span></div>
var foo = $("<div>");
foo[0].id = "foo";
var Bar = $("<span>");
Bar.text("Bar");
foo.append(Bar);
```

This type of pattern should be used when recreating the structure from your JSON.

```
var output = $("#allResults");
for (i in response) {
    var pair = $("<div>");
    pair[0].id = response[i].ID;
    pair.text(response[i].name);

    output.append(pair);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser version, you might be able to use [template strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings), which allow more readable code. In your case:

```
output += `<div id="${response[i].ID}">${response[i].NAME}</div>`;
```

Note the back-quote or backtick <kbd>`</kbd>
However, a templating engine would be better suited for bigger content.

Comment: I was looking for a tempting engine of some form as my production code is a lot busier & becoming unmanageable.  Thank you for your response though as it would work as a simpler alternative to what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? :

```js
var response = [
  { ID: 1, name: "a"},
  { ID: 2, name: "b"},
  { ID: 3, name: "c"},
  { ID: 4, name: "d"}
];
var output = "";
var divElement = "<div id='$id'>$name</div>"
for (i in response) {
    var ID = response[i].ID
    var name = response[i].name
    output += divElement.replace("$id",ID).replace("$name",name)
}

$("#allResults").html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="allResults">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use single quotes to avoid escaping, like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/vLcmjj05/)

```
output += '<div id="'+ID+'">'+name+'</div>';
```

Comment: I've reached a point where I have a ton of code & its just messy (& doesn't look the right colours in Brackets!).  I'm looking at Handlebars as per SLaks recommendation.

Comment: Sure templating would be better

Answer (score 0):

Try [JSON.Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Example: `JSON.stringify(data)`